# Why does my SWT Shell always comes up in the background?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

When I start my SWT Application from Eclipse, the Shell always starts up in the background, with the IDE in front of it.

I tried everything, like setting the focus, activating the shell, etc.

Did someone else experience the same behaviour and maybe even solved it?

Answer (score 3):

When you activate a [Shell](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell.html) (usually via the `open()` method), SWT asks the window manager on your given platform to make the shell active.  However, depending on the window manager, the shell might not become the top-most shell on the desktop.  [Here's an article](http://book.javanb.com/swt-the-standard-widget-toolkit/ch11lev1sec4.html) with some interesting info about opening shells (see section "11.4.6 Opening a Shell").

If this is the cause of your issue, you may be able to use the **`forceActive()`** method of the [Shell](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell.html) class to force the shell to become active.  However, depending on your application, you may not want to adopt this approach.  The following is a **warning** from the article:

> Most Programs Should Never Need to Use
>   forceActive()
>
> Forcing a shell to be active should be
>   reserved for those occasions when you
>   must get the attention of the user
>   (which is almost never). After all, do
>   you like it when another window steals
>   your keystrokes?

Answer (score -1):

Double check your manifest to see if you're missing anything.  That is to say if you are doing this via Eclipse RCP

Comment: What do you mean by "check your manifest"? My appname.manifest contains this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
 <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86" name="IKOffice" type="win32"/>
 <description>IKOffice Product</description>
 <dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" 
    version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86" 
    publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"/>
  </dep...>
 </dep...>
</ass...>